# Issue parsing protocol buffer ANY data in C++

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I am new to protocol buffers and I am having issues with multiple messages using Any data.
I am not sure if I am using it correctly.

I have the following in message.proto

```
import "google/protobuf/any.proto";

message config {
    string ip = 1;
    string username = 2;
    string serialnumber = 3;
};

message userdata {
    string username = 1;
};

message ServerMessage {
    config = 1;
    userdata = 2;
    google.protobuf.Any data = 3;
};
```

I am trying to serialize and send the data like below

```
ServerMessage server_msg;
google::protobuf::Any any;
server_msg.mutable_userdata()->set_username("test");

any.PackFrom(server_msg);
boost::asio::streambuf sbuf;
ostream serialized(&sbuf);
any.SerializeToOstream(&serialized);
```

On the receiving side, I try to deserialize like below

```
userdata msg;
google::protobuf::Any any;

any.ParseFromArray(message.data(), message.size()); 

if (any.Is<userdata>()) {
     std::cout<<"It is a userdata mesage"<<std::endl;
}
if (any.Is<config>()) {
     std::cout<<"it is a config message"<<std::endl;
}

if (any.UnpackTo(&msg)) {
    std::cout<<msg.username()<<std::endl;
} else {
     std::cout<<"could not unpack"<<std::endl;
}
```

The packing doesn't complain. But it is not able to unpack or determine the message type.

Am I packing it wrong?
I really appreciate your help with this!

Comment: What is the `message` in your `receiving` side ?

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert on Protobuf, but I think the problem is that you are packing a `ServerMessage` and unpacking a `userdata`.

You should unpack a `ServerMessage` and then access the `userdata()` member.